# What is the best approach for many routes / pages and self-made template in Flutter, for mobile?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

- I started to build an app in Android Studio using Flutter (Dart). I
  want to insert into the app a summary of the two books, so one it will have
  35 routes (or pages) and the other another 35 routes (or pages).
- At this moment my app looks like this: I have a **Intro_Page** with a
  button that routes to the **Main_Page**. From the Main_Page there are
  **two buttons**: one for **BookA**, the other for **BookB**. After entering the **BookA** the user, after the text, will find another
  button to the next page, **BookA_1** and on this page another button
  to **BookA_2** etc.

---

**My question are:**

1. Is there any way to use a template that can be reused for each page?
2. I have to put all the code into the main.dart file or I can make a dart file for each page and navigate between them with
   buttons?
3. Is there any possible way to create a self-made template that it uses the design layout in all the pages so I don't have to rewrite the code for 
   one of each? Just the layout not the content (the text).
4. Is there any other better way to do this?

---

PS: Any other suggestion will be helpful.

**Thank you very much** if you answer this question!

Comment: If you are well aware of mobile app development then .dart is not a major difference. It's about logic how you write. Create one layout and programmatically load next content on button click.

Comment: I started 5 days ago. I understand the logic of it but I don't know how to implement it, yet.

Comment: The answer is really big and `StackOverflow` is not the right platform for it. I suggest to google some basic sample code of displaying text, and then simply you need to change it on button click.

Comment: I already did it in a basic form. I have the feeling that it is not the best way (because I have to repeat a lot of code if I do it in this manner), that's why I am posting it here for some new approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can create one generic class for routing, in that you can just reduce the navigation code.

You can create one class like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyNavigator {
  static navigate({BuildContext context, Widget page}) async {
    await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
        return page;
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

And use it as

```
MyNavigator.navigate(context: context, page: BookA());
```

I hope it will help you.

------------------------------------ UPDATE ---------------------------------

Also you can use extension methods as well.

> For this to work, you'll need `Dart 2.7` minimum!

Implementation for extension method is as follows

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension NavigatorHelper on Widget {
  goHere(BuildContext context) async {
    await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => this),
    );
  }
}
```

And you can use it as

```
BookA().goHere(context);
```

In my opinion extension method is good way.
You can use both.

Comment: I have updated answer, You can check that method as well.
If this answer really solves your problem please accept this answer.